# Specify color type for bar graph pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created the following bar graph using pylab

[image]

For each bar graph is there a way to specify the color? Below is the code that I have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


month = ["dec-09", "jan", "feb"]
n = len(month)

air = np.array([383.909, 395.913, 411.714])

ind = np.arange(n)
width = 0.35

print(n)
print(ind)

plt.bar(ind, air, width, color="yellow")

plt.ylabel("KWH")
plt.title("winter")
plt.xticks(ind+width/2, ("dec-09", "jan", "feb"))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The docstring for `plt.bar` says:

```
Make a bar plot.

Make a bar plot with rectangles bounded by:

  `left`, `left` + `width`, `bottom`, `bottom` + `height`
        (left, right, bottom and top edges)

Parameters
----------
left : sequence of scalars
    the x coordinates of the left sides of the bars

[snip]

color : scalar or array-like, optional
    the colors of the bar faces
```

So you can pass a list of colors to `plt.bar` and it will color each bar separately.

So your example becomes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

month = ["dec-09", "jan", "feb"]
n = len(month)

air = np.array([383.909, 395.913, 411.714])

ind = np.arange(n)
width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(ind, air, width, color=["yellow", 'cornflowerblue', 'darkgreen'])

ax.set_ylabel("KWH")
ax.set_title("winter")
ax.set_xticks(ind+width/2)
ax.set_xticklabels(("dec-09", "jan", "feb"))
```

[image]